# Columns index has to be unique for fixed format error in pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, hdf

I got `ValueError: Columns index has to be unique for fixed format` when I tried to save a dataframe which I formed by combining multiple **time series** dataframe. This is the sample of what I have done

```
df1=pd.concat([d1,d2,d3,d4],axis=1]
df2=pd.DataFrame(d5)
df3=pd.concat([d6,d7,d8],axis=1]

main_df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
main_df=main_df.dropna()
main_df.head()
```

till here it works fine but when I tried to save those data into a HDF5 file its giving me this error `Columns index has to be unique for fixed format`

```
fi=pd.read_hdf("data.h5")
fi['df']=main_df #this line cause the error
```

Comment: Do you need duplicate columns names? Simpliest solution is rename duplicates column names.

Comment: Yes I have some columns with same name what is the best way to rename all duplicated columns. I have a very big dataset >30 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count `duplicates`, [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `0` if necessary and add it to original columns names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], columns = list('abbc'))
print (df)
   a  b  b  c
0  1  2  3  4

s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = s + s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).replace({'0':''})
print (df)
   a  b  b1  c
0  1  2   3  4
```